# Compiling and running Fraunhofer Versatile Video Decoder (VVdeC) using Cmake on windows

Tags: windows, cmake, compilation

I am trying to compile Fraunhofer Versatile Video Decoder (VVdeC) https://github.com/fraunhoferhhi/vvdec from source code using cmake-gui to run it on windows.
I have successfully compiled it but how do i run vvdec to play VVC codec videos? There are no executable working. I have never compiled and run a software from source code before.

Here is the build log

> The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
> The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
> Detecting C compiler ABI info
> Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
> Detecting C compile features
> Detecting C compile features - done
> Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
> Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
> Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/g++.exe - skipped
> Detecting CXX compile features
> Detecting CXX compile features - done
> CMAKE_MODULE_PATH: updating module path to: C:/temp/vvdec-1.4.0/cmake/modules
> Performing Test SUPPORTED_Werror_unused_command_line_argument
> Performing Test SUPPORTED_Werror_unused_command_line_argument - Failed
> Performing Test SUPPORTED_msse4_1
> Performing Test SUPPORTED_msse4_1 - Success
> Performing Test SUPPORTED_msse2
> Performing Test SUPPORTED_msse2 - Success
> Performing Test SUPPORTED_mavx
> Performing Test SUPPORTED_mavx - Success
> Performing Test HAVE_INTRIN_mm_storeu_si16
> Performing Test HAVE_INTRIN_mm_storeu_si16 - Failed
> Performing Test HAVE_INTRIN_mm_storeu_si32
> Performing Test HAVE_INTRIN_mm_storeu_si32 - Failed
> Performing Test HAVE_INTRIN_mm_storeu_si64
> Performing Test HAVE_INTRIN_mm_storeu_si64 - Failed
> Performing Test HAVE_INTRIN_mm_loadu_si32
> Performing Test HAVE_INTRIN_mm_loadu_si32 - Failed
> Performing Test HAVE_INTRIN_mm_loadu_si64
> Performing Test HAVE_INTRIN_mm_loadu_si64 - Failed
> Performing Test HAVE_INTRIN_mm256_zeroupper
> Performing Test HAVE_INTRIN_mm256_zeroupper - Success
> Looking for pthread.h
> Looking for pthread.h - not found
> Found Threads: TRUE
> Performing Test SUPPORTED_mxsave
> Performing Test SUPPORTED_mxsave - Success
> Performing Test SUPPORTED_msse4_2
> Performing Test SUPPORTED_msse4_2 - Success
> Performing Test SUPPORTED_mavx2
> Performing Test SUPPORTED_mavx2 - Success
> Some bitstream files are missing.
> If you want to run tests, reconfigure with -DVVDEC_ENABLE_BITSTREAM_DOWNLOAD=ON
> (or using top level Makefile: make test enable-bitstream-download=1)
> Configuring done
> Generating done

[image]
[image]

Comment: "I have successfully compiled it" - How exactly have you compiled it? What actions have you taken? What commands have you entered? Note, that in CMake GUI you can only **configure** a project, building the project should be performed by a build tool corresponding to the [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) you have specified when configure.

Comment: What kind of build tool do i need?

Comment: As you can guess from the generator name - "Codeblocks - MinGW Makefiles" - the configured project is intended to be built with Codeblocks: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/generator/CodeBlocks.html or with `mingw32-make` tool: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/generator/MinGW%20Makefiles.html

Comment: Thanx for the help.

Comment: CMake won't configure a project for a build tool which you don't have. Just run the tool which corresponds to the generator.